# Using defaultdict to parse multi delimiter file

Tags: python, python-2.7, defaultdict

I need to parse a file which has contents that look like this:

```
20  31022550    G   1396    =:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  A:2:60.00:33.00:37.00:2:0:0.02:0.02:40.00:2:0.98:126.00:0.98    C:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  G:1391:60.00:36.08:36.97:719:672:0.51:0.01:7.59:719:0.49:126.00:0.50    T:1:60.00:33.00:37.00:0:1:0.37:0.02:47.00:0:0.00:126.00:0.18    N:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  +A:2:60.00:0.00:37.00:2:0:0.67:0.01:0.00:2:0.65:126.00:0.65
20  31022551    A   1271    =:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  A:960:60.00:35.23:36.99:496:464:0.50:0.00:6.38:496:0.49:126.00:0.52 C:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  G:13:60.00:35.00:35.92:4:9:0.13:0.02:44.92:4:0.98:126.00:0.37   T:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  N:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  +G:288:60.00:0.00:37.00:171:117:0.57:0.01:8.17:171:0.54:126.00:0.53 +GG:9:60.00:0.00:37.00:5:4:0.71:0.03:23.67:5:0.50:126.00:0.57   +GGG:1:60.00:0.00:37.00:1:0:0.51:0.03:14.00:1:0.24:126.00:0.24
```

After parsing I would want it to look

```
20  31022550    G   1396    =   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022550    G   1396    A   2   60  33  37  2   0   0.02    0.02    40  2   0.98    126
20  31022550    G   1396    C   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022550    G   1396    G   1391    60  36.08   36.97   719 672 0.51    0.01    7.59    719 0.49    126
20  31022550    G   1396    T   1   60  33  37  0   1   0.37    0.02    47  0   0   126
20  31022550    G   1396    N   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022550    G   1396    +A  2   60  0   37  2   0   0.67    0.01    0   2   0.65    126
20  31022551    A   1271    =   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022551    A   1271    A   960 60  35.23   36.99   496 464 0.5 0   6.38    496 0.49    126
20  31022551    A   1271    C   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022551    A   1271    G   13  60  35  35.92   4   9   0.13    0.02    44.92   4   0.98    126
20  31022551    A   1271    T   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022551    A   1271    N   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  31022551    A   1271    +G  288 60  0   37  171 117 0.57    0.01    8.17    171 0.54    126
20  31022551    A   1271    +GG 9   60  0   37  5   4   0.71    0.03    23.67   5   0.5 126
20  31022551    A   1271    +GGG    1   60  0   37  1   0   0.51    0.03    14  1   0.24    126
```

I have more lines where it increments based on `column[1]` 31022550...31022NNN

## Code

What I am trying to do here is to only print certain parts of the file with this pseudo code keeping the `column[1]` as key

```
from collections import defaultdict
ids = defaultdict(list)

with open('~/file.tsv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = line.strip().split('\t')
        pos = (lines[0:3])
        for ele in lines[4:]:
            # print pos
            p = pos[1].strip()
            base = ele.split(':')[0]
            ids[p] = {
                'pos': pos[0].strip(),
                'base': base,
                'count': ele.split(':')[1],
                '_pos': ele.split(':')[5],
                '_neg': ele.split(':')[6]
                }
\
for k,v in ids.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

## Output

```
31022550 {'count': '2', 'base': '+A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '2'}
31022551 {'count': '1', 'base': '+GGG', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '1'}
```

Not sure why I do not see all the fields that 31022550 holds as key value pair.

Comment: Where is the output for `31022550`? You only showed output for `31022440` and `31022441`, for which there are no inputs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow glad you replied, apologies rookie mistake that is indeed output for 550 and not 440 changed my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning only the last dictionary to your `p` key:

```
ids[p] = {
    'pos': pos[0].strip(),
    'base': base,
    'count': ele.split(':')[1],
    '_pos': ele.split(':')[5],
    '_neg': ele.split(':')[6]
}
```

This bypasses the factory for new keys altogether; you are just assigning a dictionary value instead. If you wanted to build a **list** of dictionaries per key, you'd need to use `list.append()`:

```
ids[p].append({
    'pos': pos[0].strip(),
    'base': base,
    'count': ele.split(':')[1],
    '_pos': ele.split(':')[5],
    '_neg': ele.split(':')[6]
})
```

This looks up the `ids[p]` value (which then is created as an empty list if the key does not yet exist), and you then append your dictionary to the end of that list.

I'd simplify the code somewhat using the `csv` module to handle splitting of the lines:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
ids = defaultdict(list)

with open('~/file.tsv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        pos, key = row[:2]
        for elems in row[4:]:
            elems = elems.split(':')
            ids[key].append({
                'pos': pos,
                'base': elems[0],
                'count': elems[1],
                '_pos': elems[5],
                '_neg': elems[6]
            })

for key, rows in ids.iteritems():
    for row in rows:
        print '{}\t{}'.format(key, row)
```

This produces:

```
31022550    {'count': '0', 'base': '=', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '2', 'base': 'A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '2'}
31022550    {'count': '0', 'base': 'C', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '1391', 'base': 'G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '672', '_pos': '719'}
31022550    {'count': '1', 'base': 'T', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '1', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '0', 'base': 'N', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '2', 'base': '+A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '2'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': '=', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '960', 'base': 'A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '464', '_pos': '496'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'C', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '13', 'base': 'G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '9', '_pos': '4'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'T', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'N', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '288', 'base': '+G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '117', '_pos': '171'}
31022551    {'count': '9', 'base': '+GG', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '4', '_pos': '5'}
31022551    {'count': '1', 'base': '+GGG', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '1'}
```

Comment: That worked, I had a trailing question when I try to use `pos` as key here `ids[pos].append I see this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' is this not the right approach?

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher: you seem to have assigned a list to `pos`, while in my updated code I set `pos` to the first element in the row (so a single string).

Comment: makes more sense now, appreciate help on weekend and it was nice hearing your tips on talk python podcast..

Comment: I'll readup on how to use key as column header and write to a file.

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher: you could add the key to each of the dictionaries, and then use a `csv.DictWriter()` object to produce an output CSV file.

Comment: If you have issues with writing out data perhaps that's a good subject for a new question. :-)

Comment: done here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266219/writing-defaultdictlist-to-file