# Writing defaultdict(list) to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, defaultdict

Previously asked a question [Using defaultdict to parse multi delimiter file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264408/using-defaultdict-to-parse-multi-delimiter-file/46264451?noredirect=1#comment79494732_46264451)

While I do get the desired output based on the code, I am struggling to write it to a file as a table in this form

```
         count pos _pos _neg
31022550     
31022550    
31022550    
31022550
```

ids:

```
for key, rows in ids.iteritems():
     for row in rows:
         print '{}\t{}'.format(key, row)

31022550    {'count': '0', 'base': '=', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '2', 'base': 'A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '2'}
31022550    {'count': '0', 'base': 'C', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '1391', 'base': 'G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '672', '_pos': '719'}
31022550    {'count': '1', 'base': 'T', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '1', '_pos': '0'}
31022440    {'count': '0', 'base': 'N', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022550    {'count': '2', 'base': '+A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '2'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': '=', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '960', 'base': 'A', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '464', '_pos': '496'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'C', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '13', 'base': 'G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '9', '_pos': '4'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'T', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '0', 'base': 'N', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '0'}
31022551    {'count': '288', 'base': '+G', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '117', '_pos': '171'}
31022551    {'count': '9', 'base': '+GG', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '4', '_pos': '5'}
31022551    {'count': '1', 'base': '+GGG', 'pos': '20', '_neg': '0', '_pos': '1'}
```

## Code

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for k, v in ids.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Comment: can you provide the contents of `ids` in your question?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated post

Comment: Simplest: in place of `print '{}\t{}'.format(key, row)` do `writer.writerow([key, row['count'],  row['pos'], row['_pos'], row['_neg']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this (python 2):

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # binary is better, avoids blank lines in some python 2 versions
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")
    keys=["count","pos","_pos","_neg"]
    writer.writerow([""]+keys)
    for k, vl in ids.iteritems():
        for v in vl:
            writer.writerow([k] + [v[key] for key in keys])
```

you need a double loop to iterate on the lists for each key. I have stored the column names in a list, so I can reuse it to build the rows in a list comprehension & for the title as well (first item doesn't have a title, I just left it blank)

now it looks like this:

```
        count   pos     _pos    _neg
31022550        0       20      0       0
31022550        2       20      2       0
31022550        0       20      0       0
```

(slightly shifted because tab character isn't wide enough, but not an issue to read it back)

Python 3 users would have to change:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
```

by

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w',newline="") as f:
```

and

```
for k, vl in ids.iteritems():
```

by

```
for k, vl in ids.items():  # also works in python 2
```

note that the `writerow` double loop could be replaced by a single line, a double-loop, flat generator comprehension passed to `writerows`, faster to execute:

```
writer.writerows([k] + [v[key] for key in keys] for k, vl in ids.items() for v in vl)
```

Comment: Why not use a `csv.DictWriter()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's not that good with DictWriter: 1) the title line isn't compliant with the keys (id is written as an empty string) and 2) not all dict data is written, which creates an error when writing `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames`

Comment: You can use an empty field name / key. And you can configure DictWriter to ignore extra keys.

Comment: `extrasaction="ignore"` yes good point. But the data isn't in the dict. "id" is a key, and the rest is in the dict. You would need to rebuild a custom dict to be able to use DictWriter. (and there's the header issue too). That isn't adapted because the way the input data is organized @MartijnPieters

Comment: Just add an extra key or suggest the OP put the extra key into the duct when building :-)

Comment: yeah, probably. But there's an extra hindrance: there's 1 main key for a list of dicts... At least your comments made me realize I should use DictWriter more often.

Comment: So? Note that I wrote the code in the other post. That can be adjusted to just add the key there. The OP could even just write out as the rows directly rather than collect into lists.

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me solve a problem I was working on. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answer below:

```
#Writing an instance of  Defaultdict(list) into a file is simpler than I 
# thought. Polymorphisms can solve this problem. 
# Create an object (dd) of type Defaultdict(list) (mydd) which is a subtype of
# dict, Assign mydd to dd and save dd into a file as json.

from collections import defaultdict
import json
dd = defaultdict(list)
dd["horse"].append("Mammal")
dd["Eagle"].append("Bird")
dd["Python"].append("Reptile")
print(dd)

# Let save this defaultdict instance in a file
mydd = dict
mydd = dd
print("#" * 70)
print(f"printing mydd ----:{mydd} ---- an instance of a dict")
# Now saving dd under mydd, an instance of a dict.
print("#" * 70)
with open("mydd.json", "w") as f:
    print("writing my defaultdict object into a file")
    f.write(json.dumps(mydd))
    f.close()
print("#" * 70)
    
mydd1 = dict
# opening the file and store it into an object from the file

with open("mydd.json", "r") as f:
    print("opening my defaultdict object into a file")
    mydd1 = json.load(f)
    print("printing the json file just saved above", mydd1)
```

OUTPUT IN TEXT

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'horse': ['Mammal'], 'Eagle': ['Bird'], 'Python': ['Reptile']})
######################################################################
printing mydd ----:defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'horse': ['Mammal'], 'Eagle': ['Bird'], 'Python': ['Reptile']}) ---- an instance of a dict
######################################################################
writing my defaultdict object into a file
######################################################################
opening my defaultdict object into a file
printing the json file just saved above {'horse': ['Mammal'], 'Eagle': ['Bird'], 'Python': ['Reptile']}
```

[output of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbMMn.png)